# Swift Calling method from deeply nested UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm getting really confused about calling methods on a dynamically added subview. I know I'm making a newbie mistake but I just can't figure it out.

My hierarchy looks something like this:

```
TableView
    - TableViewCell
         - CustomContainer (UIVIew subclass)
                - Widget (UIView subclass)
                     - myButton
```

The `Widget` is added to the `CustomContainer` via `view.addSubview(widget)`

I have an @IBAction on myButton that I want to call `myFunc` declared in the `Widget` class (below the @IBAction):

```
@IBAction func myButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        myFunc()
    }
```

...

```
func myFunc(){
    print("myButton was just tapped")
}
```

When I tap the button I get an error in the console that I can't resolve: `[myApp.CustomContainer myButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

My objective is to have all the methods that relate to the Widget contained in the Widget class or somewhere similar that makes this logical and easy to move around.

I've tried lots of different things but to be honest I'm now just casting around in the dark. If anyone can suggest an approach I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `sender` should be `UIButton` not `AnyObject`. And make sure you have referenced the outlet correctly to your class and there are no duplicates. And while changing AnyObject to UIButton, remove the action outlet completely and add it again, you have to remove from `Connections inspector` on the right.

Comment: In your hierarchy you mention that you use a UITableView, are you using Dynamic Prototype Cells or Static Cells?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 thanks - I tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: @Dilts Prototype cells

Comment: @James is your button IBAction in the UITableView class or in your UITableViewCell class?

Comment: @Dilts in the Widget class :-p

Comment: @James You're getting `[myApp.CustomContainer myButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`, so your button is trying to call the `myButtonTapped` selector from the CustomContainter class, but it should be in your widget class, as you said. Check to see if your IBAction is hooked up correctly to the right class and if your UIButton is actually in the widget view hierarchy.

Comment: @Dilts My thinking was that the CustomContainer can have multiple Widgets, each with it's own methods that don't need to interact with any siblings. Keeping the methods with the Widget seemed the most logic place for them.

Comment: @Dilts Thanks for the suggestion - "your UIButton is actually in the widget view hierarchy" how would you do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114778/discussion-between-dilts-and-james).

Comment: @Dilts Thanks for your help on this. I ended up rebuilding that part of the app and the way I was doing it worked fine. I think the issue was with an old IBOutlet/IBAction that had been deleted/disconnected. Such a simple issue but super-tricky to track down and fix.

Comment: @James I'm glad to have helped. Good luck on the app! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some quick investigation and a little demo: Add you `@IBAction` function to your custom UITableViewCell subclass.

[image: @IBAction in your custom UITableViewCell subclass]

When adding the the Widget with the UIButton to the CustomContainer, make sure it's selector is YourCustomUITableViewCellClass.myButtonTapped. Another step you might also want to consider is to refactor your code and maybe not use such a deep hierarchy.